# Block Callers List

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to create a program that will let me block calls from numbers that i could save in a list
If its not possible in the current version is there any word if this may be supported in the next version that is releasing later in the year
Links to any info to read would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No, Windows Phone doesn't allow third party apps to run in the background (restrictive multitasking is allowed) and also doesn't allow applications to interfere with the Phone itself.

Without the SDK for WP8 there is no way to tell you if this situation has changed yet.